# Using if else inside array-php

Tags: php, arrays

being new to php i am not ble to figure out how to use `if else` inside php array. i tried to do something like this

```
function column_title($item){
        $status=false;
        if($item->uTestimonials_approval =='0')
           $status=false;
         else
          $status=true;

        //Build row actions
        $actions = array(
             $status ? 'unapprove'      => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&id=%s">Unapprove</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'unapprove',$item-> uTestimonials_id),:
            'approve1'      => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&id=%s">Approve</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'approve',$item-> uTestimonials_id),

            'delete'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&id=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item-> uTestimonials_id),
        );

        //Return the title contents
        return sprintf('%1$s <span style="color:silver">(id:%2$s)</span>%3$s',
            /*$1%s*/ $item-> uTestimonials_message,
            /*$2%s*/ $item-> uTestimonials_id,
            /*$3%s*/ $this->row_actions($actions)
        );
    }
```

but i am getting following parsing exception

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW
```

can any one help me to find what exactly i am doing wrong thanks in advance

**I am perfectly fine for negative voting but its always better to specify why some one did that so that person can improve him/herself**

Comment: What did you intend to do by doing $status ? 'unapprove'?

Comment: @Jeune i am working on some wordpress functionality and based on the approval status i need to show certain text to use so i am using this.

Comment: To let you know, whole your code, with all this sprintf and ternary being **extremely unreadable**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **cannot** do this for a key value:

```
 $status ? 'unapprove'
```

Try something like this instead:

```
    //Build row actions
    $ap = 'approve';
    $key = 'approve1';
    if($status){             
       $ap = 'unapprove';
       $key = 'unapprove';
    }
    $actions = array(
        $key => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&id=%s">'.$ap.'</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],$ap,$item-> uTestimonials_id),:
        'delete' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&id=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item-> uTestimonials_id),
    );
```

Comment: any idea how i can achieve the desired thing as i have to use key and a value against it

Comment: @user what about just a regular if setting a variable **before** array definition code, eh?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I added that ^_^

Comment: No need to do that, you can use shorthand notation for an array key. He just didn't specify the else portion of it that's why it was throwing an error.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder look at the OP's code, the else was specified, but in the wrong place.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: You're still somewhat correct, because for the value a second ternary operator can be used as well. However ... ;)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that inside the array definition.

Instead, you could add these to the array after the definition like this:

```
$actions = array(
    'delete'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&id=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item-> uTestimonials_id),
);

if ($status) {
    $actions['unapprove'] = sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&id=%s">Unapprove</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'unapprove',$item-> uTestimonials_id);
}
else {
    $actions['approve'] = sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&id=%s">Approve</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'approve',$item-> uTestimonials_id);
}
```